# Using variation of parameters, how can we assume that nether $y_1$, $y_2$ equal zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Here's the problem I have been given:

Use the method of variation of parameters to find a general solution of the following differential equation:

$$
a_1y''+a_2y'+a_3y=f(x)
$$

And linearly independent solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ are known.

Note: $a_1, a_2,$ and $a_3$ are constants.

---

Assume that $y_p$ is of the form $u_1y_1+u_2y_2$ where $u_1, u_2$ are functions.

Now to solve the system of equations obtained by differentiating $y_p$:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_1'y_1+u_2'y_2=0 \\
u_1'y_1'+u_2'y_2'=f(x)
\end{cases}
$$

to solve the first equation for $u_1'$, we get
$$
u_1'=-\frac{u_2'y_2}{y_1}
$$

My question is how we know that $y_1$ cannot be zero depending on the value of the given independent variable $t$, and if it doesn't matter, why?

Comment: It doesn't matter because the solution to any PVI will be unique, so after you find a solution (by those seemingly unrigorous methods), to be perfectly rigorous you just make sure it is a solution and then conclude all is fine due to uniqueness of solutions. In fact, if you just want to find a solution, then you just need to ignore possible divisions by $0$ and then replace whatever you get in the equation and see it works.

Comment: @GitGud I'm not sure what you mean by PVI, and why can we just ignore the division by zero?

Comment: I meant IVP, my bad. It's not that you can exactly ignore division by $0$, it's that whatever you get in the end will be a solution and that you can verify yourself. Is this clearer?

Comment: @GitGud I'm asked to find a general solution, I'll edit my question to be more clear. And yes, it is a bit clearer.

Comment: I think he meant IVP (Initial Value Problem). Also, it is asking you to use Variation of Parameters.

Comment: @Tyzoid Amzoti, the differential equations expert has arrived. Be happy.

Comment: @Amzoti I am using variation of parameters. This is the method the book uses, but never fully explains it.

Comment: $y_1$ and $y_2$ are fundamental system, so $y_1(x), y_2(x) \not \equiv 0$. To find $y_1$ or $y_2$ of linear homogeneous system, one need to solve $a_1 \lambda^2 + a_2 \lambda + a_3 = 0$, and then take $y_{1,2} = \exp \left( \lambda_{12} x\right)$, non of which gives $0$.

Comment: @kaster what if my solutions are imaginary? Applying Euler's formula yields sine and cosine.