# Doubt about Higher Order Differential Equations (Linear and Non Homogeneous)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

**Theory that I've been taught:**

Algorithm to solve the following equations:
\begin{equation*}
x^{(n)} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_jx^{(n-j)}+b(t)
\end{equation*}
First, we associate the linear homogeneous equation associated and find the general solution for it, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
\overline{x}(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}C_j(t)\overline{\varphi}_j(t)
\end{equation*}
where $\overline{\varphi}_j(t)$ represent the fundamental solutions of the linear equation. After this, we try to find the functions $C_j(.)$ such that they verify the following conditions:
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}C'_j(t)\overline{\varphi}_j^{(k)}(t) \equiv 0, \quad 0\leq k \leq n-2
\end{equation*}
and such that:
\begin{equation*}
x(t) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} C_j(t)\overline{\varphi}_j(t)
\end{equation*}
is a solution of the initial equation.
From this we get the system:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}C'_j(t)\overline{\varphi}_j^{(k)}(t) \equiv 0, \quad 0\leq k \leq n-2 \\[10pt]
\sum_{j=1}^{n}C'_j\overline{\varphi}^{(n-1)}(t) \equiv b(t)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

By solving this system we basically solve the exericse.

**My doubts:** For equations of order 2, I can work it out in perfection, but for higher order equations I obviously have a system with 2 equations and with 3 variables, which doesn't have a unique solution, so, my question is: is this normal? Below I show an example.

**Example:** Solving $x^{(3)}-x' = 2t$:

After some calculations, I found out that the homogeneous equation associated has the general solution:
\begin{equation*}
\overline{x}(t) = C_1 + C_2e^t + C_3e^{-t}, \quad C_1,C_2,C_3 \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation*}
So, now I take:
\begin{equation*}
x(t) = C_1(t) + C_2(t)e^t + C_3(t)e^{-t} \\[5pt]
C'_1(t)+C'_2(t)e^t+C'_3(t)e^{-t} = 0
\end{equation*}
Which gets me to the system:
\begin{cases}
C'_1(t) + C'_2(t)e^t + C'_3(t)e^{-t} = 0 \\[10pt]
C'_2(t)e^t + C'_3(t)e^{-t} = 2t
\end{cases}
Which lead me to:
\begin{cases}
C'_1(t) = -2t \\[10pt]
C'_2(t) = 2te^{-t}-C'_3(t)e^{-2t}
\end{cases}
Now, I have multiple solutions, which is where I have doubts.

If anyone could help me, I would be really thankfull.

Comment: I find it helpful to rewrite a higher-order equation as a system of first-order equations, and compute as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2833772/1242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that with $n-2=1$ you also get the homogeneous equation with the derivatives of the basis function
$$
C_1'·0+C_2'e^t-C_3'e^{-t}=0.
$$

Comment: Thanks Lutz, do you mind explaining the part of the "$k$" better? I don't seem to understand how does it change from case to case (I always take $k=0$) (and from your answer I suposse you took $k=1$ and $k=0$, forming a 3 equation system, is this it?)

Comment: You get an equation for every $k$, so $n-1$ homogeneous ones for $k=0,...,n-2$ and the last one that contains the inhomogeneity. In principle you could put arbitrary terms on the right side of the first $n-1$ equations, but you would have to compensate that in the last equation. Only by random chance or very careful planning will this give an overall simplification.