How come the condition imposed in Variation of Parameters does not yield an inconsistent system?
For variation of paramters, one moves to solve the system
$$y'' + py' + qy = g(t)$$
by modifying the complimentary solution
$$y_c = C_1y_1 + C_2y_2$$
to find a particular solution of the form
$$y_p = u_1y_1 + u_2y_2,$$
where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are now arbitrary functions rather than arbitrary real numbers. This part seems fine to me - even if the particular solution has nothing to do with the complimentary solutions, the
$u_i$ functions could simply be their reciprocals (which always exist, since neither $y_i$ can be zero), so this supposition does not really restrict the answer at all.
Now, there are many choices of $u_i$ that solve the original differential equation, but we only need one combination to yield one particular solution, so we wish to impose a restriction relating $u_1$ and $u_2$. The restriction chosen is
$$y_1u_1' + y_2u_2' = 0,$$
since this massively simplifies computation in the next step.
My question is this: when imposing an arbitrary restriction on a system of equations, you either reduce the number of free variables by one or the new equation is inconsistent, yielding no solutions. How do we know that this restriction will not be inconsistent? In other words, how do we know that a particular solution satisfying
$$y_1u_1' + y_2u_2' = 0$$
must exist?
Edit: Note that the answer to the linked question by Michael_1812 addressed my concerns. Feel free to read the full answer, but the basic idea is that variation of parameters is messier but still works if the constraint imposed is instead
$$y_1u_1' + y_2u_2' = \Phi(t),$$
which imposes no restriction since $\Phi$ is chosen arbitrarily. Furthermore, $\Phi$ cancels when solving for $y_p$, so since $\Phi$ does not influence the final answer, a specific and convenient choice will definitely not yield an inconsistent system.

@Dominique, the second answer in that thread is the same answer linked below, and is the first I've seen that answers my question. There are lots of answers on here deriving why it makes sense to replace $C_1$ with $u_1(t)$, but this is the first I've seen that justifies the constraint.

Here's one way of completely demystifying the appeareance of the constraint: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2833772/1242

Just my two cents:
The restriction in your way to find the particular solution $y_p = u_1y_1 + u_2y_2$ is not the unique way. Due to the "restriction" (or as a remedy) the particular solution does not prevent inconsistent.
In fact, the particular solution doesn't need any relationship with the homogeneous solution. For instance $y_p=1$ solves $y''+y=1$ with $y_h=c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x$.
In stead, you can assume the complete solution as $y=c_1y_1(x)+c_2y_2(x)+y_p(x)$ and insert to your original equation to find $y_p$.
The source terms are usually called forcing terms since they act as an excitation of the system from external inputs. The complete solution will be ended up in a convolution process to coordinate or intervene between the internal and external part. For a general inhomogenous 2nd ODE like
$$y''(t)-(\alpha+\beta)y'(t)+\alpha\beta y(t)=r(t),$$
of which the characteristic or eigen equation can be written as $(\mathfrak{D}-\alpha)(\mathfrak{D}-\beta)=0$, then the full solution (with distinct roots) can be expressed by
\begin{align}
y&=\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\alpha t}&e^{\beta t}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\\alpha&\beta
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}
c_{0}\\c_{1}
\end{bmatrix}+\frac{e^{\alpha t}-e^{\beta t}}{\alpha-\beta}*r(t)\\
&=\boxed{\frac{(c_1-\beta c_0)e^{\alpha t}-(c_1-\alpha c_0)e^{\beta t}}{\alpha-\beta}+\frac{e^{\alpha t}-e^{\beta t}}{\alpha-\beta}*r(t)}
\end{align}
where $c_0$ and $c_1$ are the constants from initial (Cauchy) conditions and $*$ is for the convolution.
